# Your authentication attempt was unsuccessful (for sudoer)

Tags: sudo, authentication, administrator

After installing Ubuntu I have created a new user and gave it all privileges in `/etc/sudoers`:

```
user2     ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

However now user2 cannot do admin tasks from GUI, like formatting a disk using `gparted`, and gets this error:

```
Your authentication attempt was unsuccessful
```

I'm wondering how can I fix this?

Comment: Did you try adding `user2` to the `sudo` group instead? This is the default way of granting `sudo` privilege.

Comment: No I did not. Actually running `usermod -G sudo  user2` solved the problem. Please answer and I'll accept. Thanks.

Comment: "user2 cannot do admin tasks from GUI" ... note that this will typically be using polkit, *not* `sudo`, but Ubuntu by default uses the `sudo` group to confer rights for both `sudo` and polkit.

Comment: Muru, I'll add that detail to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the user `user2` to the `sudo` group:

```
usermod -a -G sudo user2
```

This should work, and is the default way of granting `sudo` privilege.

The reason is that GUI admin rights is granted by `polkit` (and not by `sudo` directly), but in Ubuntu `polkit` uses the `sudo` group to grant its privileges as well.